# How to set the names of NIB items in Xcode 4's Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode

Back when Interface Builder was a separate application, one could rename any of the items in a nib file to anything he pleased without any impact on the operation of the final application. It was really nice for keeping things organized and helped a ton with bindings (Company Array Controller, Job Array Controller, and Person Array Controller is much better than having to choose between three items with the same name of "Array Controller").

But unless I'm missing something, this functionality seems to have vanished in Xcode 4. Is it still possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still possible to do this. IIRC it's in the 'identity' tab of the utilities pane when you have an item in the nib selected.

[image]

It's the 'Label' text field in the above screenshot.